# Using OpenID with an existing website login sytem

Tags: php, mysql, openid, attribute-exchange

I have recently implemented Google and Yahoo's OpenID endpoints into my authentication system on my site so that users can avoid creating an account on my site. Pretty common practice, right?

I have a specific question though, but first a little background information.

When I get through the three-legged authentication I used Attribute Exchange to get the user's name and email address. Currently, I am storing their OpenID (a long string that looks like this: https://me.yahoo.com/a/2Z7LplQsnI_DgtAw(... a bunch of alphanumeric) in a special field in the users table.

Let's say my users table looks like this.

```
type  id  password                          email             key
1     1   0e9212587d373ca58e9bada0c15e6fe4  test@example.com
2     1   b8d2f4a50d2b364ff2766556ba50da48  me@gmail.com      https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=AItOawll6-m_y…
2     2   6687d5d88b359ee1340717ebf0d1afc6  you@gmail.com     https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=AItOawm3-C_9…
3     1   fd193c2fa449c9d6dc201d62d5ca86d3  him@yahoo.com     https://me.yahoo.com/a/2Z7LplQsnI_DgtAw…
1     2   2e710b13b3dd787e2b15eab3dde508c2  person@site.com

types
1 = native account
2 = Google OpenID
3 = Yahoo OpenID
```

When a user logs in with a native account, the email and password are used to authenticate (duh).

When a user uses Google or Yahoo OpenID, then the OpenID (key field) is used to authenticate.

Okay, now that all the background information is out of the way... **will it be secure if I forget about storing the OpenID itself and simply use the email I got back from Attribute Exchange to authenticate the user?** Can someone spoof the third leg of an OpenID transaction or can I trust that whenever I get you@gmail.com from the Attribute Exchange portion of an OpenID transaction with Google that it is genuine and not spoofed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such an intentional breaking of the protocol will cause you major headaches in the long run.  For instance, consider cases where a user logs in using a custom-built OpenID server, but provides a @gmail.com email address.

The only information guaranteed to be absolutely consistent and reliable after an OpenID authentication exchange is the identity URL.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to know. Thanks!